# Problem syncing MS Exchange after ICS update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, exchange

After updating my T-Mobile Galaxy SII to ICS last week my Exchange account no longer will sync.  I have gone through the process of establishing it as a new account several times both with a T-Mobile tech and my organization IT tech.  It appears to get stuck at the point of downloading and I get a which screen with a circle in the middle and the word Loading underneath.  Nothing comes in: email, calendar or contacts.  When I try to send an email it gives me a connection error.
It worked fine before the update and my wife's phone, an unupdated twin, continues to sync with no problem to the same exchange server.
Does anyone have a solution to this?